# Cannot RDP to Azure VM after sysprep

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I followed the instructions [listed here to capture an image of my Azure VM](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/how-to-guides/capture-an-image/):

Now I am unable to RDP to the VM - I get the generic message "Remote Desktop can't connect to the remote computer for one of these reasons:1,2,3 etc"

The VM I'm trying to connect to is: teamsitepoc.cloudapp.net:59207

Here's what I've tried:

1. I have checked that it's started.
2. Tried re-sizing to extra small then back to small.
3. Attached the disk that was captured, giving the following:

Could anyone please advise what else I can try to troubleshoot

[image]

Comment: You sysprepped an existing Virtual Machine? or you sysprepped a local image and uploaded it?

Comment: Also, now this is very simple, but lets get it out of the way, did you download a new RDP file from the website?  The port will change as you allocate and deallocate your VM.  You may be pointed to the wrong port.

Comment: One more item.  When you capture, you capture an `Image` not a `Disk`.  An `Image` is assumed to be Sysprepped whereas a `Disk` is just a storage location.  The `Disk` can have an OS on it, but wont boot if its been sysprepped.  Likewise an `Image` cannot boot *unless* its been sysprepped.

Comment: Thanks for your response, here are my answers: 1) I sysprepped an existing Virtual Machine. 2) Yes, I did download the new RDP file, I also checked the port number against the live endpoints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is entirely possible that you encountered the shutdown bug listed at the top of the page you link to.

Unfortunately rather than updating the documentation all they did was add a warning to the top of the page and left the incorrect instructions in the actual steps so likely many other people will encounter the same issue.

The workaround is available here: [*Image capture issue / VM unexpectedly started after guest-initiated shutdown*](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/fafb9ee6-1e57-46ba-8440-27467ad986cf/image-capture-issue-vm-unexpectedly-started-after-guestinitiated-shutdown?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows)

Comment: Unfortunately, I've had no joy with the workaround either (using "quit" rather than "shutdown" for sysprep) and I've followed the instructions to the letter. All I want to do is create an image of my Windows Server 2012, but after numerous attempts the RDP session disconnects part-way through the sysprep process and renders the VM unusable. When are Microsoft going to resolve this issue?

Comment: Success! I've since tried the process on a Windows Server 2008 R2 VM and thankfully it works and I can now create VMs from my captured image.

Comment: If this has happened is there a way to recover the original VM and repair it or is the VHD (that was sysprep'd) toast?  I spent days trying to put the image together and now it looks like all is lost :(

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem, pings went through from the VMs but no RDP port open.
Then I realized that windows was still updating!!